# Connection refused after installing vsftp on Ubuntu 8.04 with fail2ban

Tags: linux, security, ftp

I have been using an Ubuntu 8.04 server with fail2ban for a while now (12+ months) and using ftp over SSH without any problems. I have a new user that needs to put files onto the server from an IP modem.

I have installed vsftp (`sudo apt-get install vsftp`) and everything installed correctly.

I have created an ftp user on the server following this guide.

Whenever I try to connect to the server with my ftp program (filezilla) I get an immediate response of:

> Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".

I have looked into fail2ban and cannot find any problems. The iptables setup is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

VSFTP config file (commented lines removed)

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=[username]
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Any ideas on what is preventing access to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSFTP ended up not being installed properly.

After removing the program and reinstalling it, everything worked fine.